# Binding DataGrid to EntitySet

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql, datagrid, one-to-many

In this example I have a Customer which can have many PhoneNumbers. These are the objects:

**The Customer**

```
[Table(Name = "Customers")]
public class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private String id;

    private String givenName;
    private String surname;

    private EntitySet<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;

    //INotifyPropertyChanged implementation was elided...

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey=true, Storage="id", Name="Id", DbType="NVarChar(10) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
    public String Id
    {
        get { return this.id; }
        set
        {
            if (this.id != value)
            {
                 this.id = value;
                 this.OnPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }
    }

    [Column(Storage="givenName", Name="GivenName", DbType="NVarChar(50) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
    public String GivenName
    {
        get { return this.givenName; }
        set
        {
            if (this.givenName != value)
            {
                this.givenName = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("GivenName");
            }
        }
    }

    [Column(Storage="surname", Name="Surname", DbType="NVarChar(50) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
    public String Surname
    {
        get { return this.surname; }
        set
        {
            if (this.surname != value)
            {
                this.surname = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Surname");
            }
        }
    }

    [Association(Name="FK_PhoneBook_Customers", Storage = "phoneNumbers", ThisKey="Id", OtherKey = "CustomerId")]
    public EntitySet<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers
    {
        get
        {
            return this.phoneNumbers;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.phoneNumbers!= value)
            {
                this.phoneNumbers.Assign(value);
                this.OnPropertyChanged("PhoneNumbers");
            }
        }
    }

    public Customer() { this.phoneNumbers = new EntitySet<PhoneNumber>(); }
}
```

**and the PhoneNumber**

```
[Table(Name = "PhoneBook")]
public class PhoneNumber: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private int id;
    private String customerId;
    private String number;

    private EntityRef<Customer> customer;

    //INotifyPropertyChanged implementation was elided...

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true, Storage="id", Name="Id", DbType="int", CanBeNull=false)]
    public int Id
    {
        get { return this.id; }
        private set
        {
            if (this.id != value)
            {
                this.id = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }
    }

    [Column(Storage="customerId", Name="CustomerId", DbType="NVarChar(10) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
    public String CustomerId
    {
        get { return this.customerId; }
        set
        {
            if (this.customerId != value)
            {
                this.customerId = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("CustomerId");
            }
        }
    }

    [Column(Storage="number", Name="Number", DbType="NVarChar(10) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
    public String Number
    {
        get { return this.number; }
        set
        {
            if (this.number != value)
            {
                this.number = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Number");
            }
        }
    }

    [Association(IsForeignKey=true, Name="FK_PhoneBook_Customers", ThisKey="CustomerId", OtherKey = "Id")]
    public Customer Customer
    {
        get { return this.customer.Entity; }
        set { this.customer.Entity = value; }
    }

    public PhoneNumber() { this.customer = new EntityRef<Customer>(); }
}
```

I have created a DataContext and got a customer(simplified version):

```
db = new DataContext(@"server=WIN-EL78137MUMS\SQLEXPRESS;database=SandBox;integrated security=SSPI");

// Get a typed table to run queries.
customers = db.GetTable<Customer>();

custQuery =
    from cust in customers
    orderby cust.Id
    select cust;

Customer = custQuery.Skip(5).Take(1).First();
```

Into the XAML I've added DataGrid and bound it to the PhoneNumbers property of Customer.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PhoneNumbers}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="CustomerId" Binding="{Binding CustomerId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number" Binding="{Binding Number, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Sorry for long intro, here is my problem along with some questions - When I'm trying to add a new phone number into the grid and call the db.SubmitChanges() I get following error message: "An attempt was made to remove a relationship between a Customer and a PhoneNumber. However, one of the relationship's foreign keys (PhoneNumber.CustomerId) cannot be set to null.". Now I don't want the user to constantly write id of the customer when he needs to add a phone number, since the right customer is already selected and I'm trying to add another number to his collection of numbers. How this could/should be done?
Additional questions are:

1. It looks that the new line is not added until Enter was pressed, if I'd enter the phone number and right after that click a button that calls db.SubmitChanges(), nothing will happen(all three collections[insert/update/delete] will be empty).
2. Do I have to hold an EntityRef in PhoneNumber? There're lot of examples out there in the wild that don't have it at all, some mention it as One-to-One connection utility.
3. In either way it's a little bit strange to me to define the EntityRef as the IsForeignKey=true, it sounds more reasonable to me that the PhoneNumber.CustomerId should be defined as ForeignKey, but when I tried to mark it with [Association(IsForeignKey=true, Name="FK_AddressBook_Customers", ThisKey="CustomerId", OtherKey = "Id")] I got this error at application start up "Could not find key member 'Id' of key 'Id' on type 'String'. The key may be wrong or the field or property on 'String' has changed name". I didn't find anything useful in the internet regarding that. Should it be marked in another way? Should it be marked at all?
4. Do I have to(or should I?) name the Foreign Key from both of the ends(EntitySet and EntityRef) with one name(like I've seen in another example and did it the same way here)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer to the primary question is quite simple, in PhoneNumber in Association attribute I forgot the Storage property. The correct property definition is as follows:

```
[Association(IsForeignKey=true, Name="FK_PhoneBook_Customers", Storage="customer", ThisKey="CustomerId", OtherKey = "Id")]
public Customer Customer
{
    get { return this.customer.Entity; }
    set { this.customer.Entity = value; }
}
```

The answer to the second question is "No.", actually without it I wouldn't even face the main problem at all. But for some reason Visual Studio creates this back reference. If anyone of you knows why it could be useful, please share your thoughts.
The answer to the third question is also "No, it shouldn't be marked at all". It became obvious once everything started to work without any association attributes attached to the PhoneNumber.CustomerId property.
I've also got a partial answer to the fourth question - "No, I don't have to give the same name from both of the ends - it will continue to work also with different names.", but may be I should give the same name(again, VS names them exactly the same) because of some unknown and unwanted consequences. Again, please advise.